# Is there any way to get user details whenever user uninstalls bot and bot is installed in personal scope only?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

> This is conversationUpdate event with membersRemoved object but that works only in the case when the bot is installed in a group and either the bot or member is removed from the group but I don't receive any callback when the bot is installed in personal scope and is removed later.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no event/information sent on this at all from Teams. There's a new event in the bot framework (latest release) called "InstallationUpdate", which I was hoping would cover this, but that also doesn't send anything, at least not at the moment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please share some doc related to this event.

Comment: Check out the change log at https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/releases . Remember though that this is bot framework itself, so whether/if/when Teams decides to implement it is another question...

Comment: I checked this event but this isn't helping at the moment. I couldn't receive anything even after subscribing to this event whenever I install or uninstall the bot.

Comment: yes, I know - I tested earlier today as well, when I saw your question - that's what I meant, that Teams doesn't send anything

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
protected override async Task OnInstallationUpdateActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IInstallationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var activity = turnContext.Activity;
    if (string.Equals(activity.Action, "Add", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // installation workflow
    }
    else
    {
        // uninstallation workflow
    }
}
```