# Which event is fired when someone uninstalls your app in Microsoft Teams

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am working on creating a bot for Microsoft Teams in C# using the Bot Framework. Users can interact with the bot and ask some questions.

When users install the app, the **OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync** event gets fired and I save some user info into my Azure database.

I have to delete user data when the app is uninstalled from the Teams.

The problem that I am facing is that I am not getting any event fired when someone uninstalls the app.

Is there any way to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to get user details whenever user uninstalls bot and bot is installed in personal scope only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63572664/is-there-any-way-to-get-user-details-whenever-user-uninstalls-bot-and-bot-is-ins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact question before yours on this site was asking basically the same question - check it out here: [Is there any way to get user details whenever user uninstalls bot and bot is installed in personal scope only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63572664/is-there-any-way-to-get-user-details-whenever-user-uninstalls-bot-and-bot-is-ins).